# python - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on OSX Yosemite

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite, ioerror

First of all, there has been a question asked on this forum regarding the same error no. that I am asking help for; however, after trying solutions mentioned there I feel my problem is different.

I am using Python 2.7 via IDLE on Mac OS X Yosemite.

I am trying to write data downloaded to a .csv file in a specific folder already created. The line of code that generates the error is

```
fc = open('%s/try.csv' % (dl_dir), 'w')
```

where

```
dl_dir = 'quandl/futures/ES'
```

The error I get is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    fc = open('%s/try.csv' % (dl_dir), 'w')
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'quandl/futures/ES/try.csv'
```

At first I executed this command without the file `try.csv` being present in the said directory since the documentation on `open` says that the command will create the file if not already present. On getting this error I created `try.csv` in the said directory, gave `'read','write'` and `'execute'` permissions on the file

```
    Parikshits-MacBook-Pro:ES parikshitbhinde$ chmod a+wrx try.csv
    Parikshits-MacBook-Pro:ES parikshitbhinde$ ls -l
    total 8
    -rwxrwxrwx  1 parikshitbhinde  staff  4 Jan 26 19:18 try.csv
```

Even after this I continue to get the same error. Any help?

**NOTE : The code works even without creating the file on Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.01**

Thanks

Comment: I see You are using a relative path. Is it possible You are running the script form different path on Mac? Try starting it with the same relative location or correct dl_dir to an absolute path.

Comment: Do you mean `dl_dir = '~/quandl/futures/ES'` ? I've tried that too with the same resulting error. If not, then can you please be more specific. Also, I just opened IDLE and ran the code, is there a way to change the working directory for IDLE?

Comment: `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will give you the path of the current python file.

Use that for relative file paths. Or use absolute path. I wouldn't rely on `~`, since that might be platform dependant, and change according to which user is running the script.

Comment: The reason that it works in Ubuntu is probably because the folder is found, even if the file isn't created yet.

Comment: I'm running commands on the interpreter, not a script. I'll try putting the commands in a script in the same directory as the csv and try running the script.

Comment: Are you able to [stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) the containing directory?

Comment: Tried  `os.stat(dl_dir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'quandl/futures/ES'`

Comment: Try `os.getcwd()`. That works from the python shell, and will return the current working directory. `os.chdir()` can be used to change working directory.

Comment: Thank you guys @KrzysztofRosiński it was indeed a path issue.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin .. I am new to Python, good to know about os.stat

Comment: Thank you @HåkenLid I tried hard to find how to change cwd using some UI option. The commands you talk about is what i was looking for.

Comment: Good. I've submitted that as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the file, since the parent directory doesn't exist, relative to the working directory.

Try `os.getcwd()` from the python shell to get the current working directory. `os.chdir()` can be used to change working directory.